# Select elements that don't have specific words in their class attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I select only `<a>` elements which doesn't have the word **gallery** inside its **id** or **class** attribute?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this selector:

```
a:not([id*=gallery], [class*=gallery])
```

This will select each `a` element that does not have “gallery” in either its `id` or its `class` atttribute value.

Or for a full ID or class name match:

```
a:not([id=gallery], [class~=gallery])
```

This will select each `a` element that does not have “gallery” as its ID or as a class name.

Comment: You can also do this a:not([id*=gallery],[class*=gallery])

Comment: @joelpittet: I guess that’s is even the correct answer since he’s looking for a disjuction and not a conjunction.

Comment: @joelpittet is correct, if case anyone wants to play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/MZDgB/

Comment: @nick-craver  that is a cool site, thanks for the jsfiddle.net link!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to go about like this:

```
$('a').each(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('class').indexOf('gallery') == -1 && $(this).attr('id').indexOf('gallery') == -1) { 
    // your code....
  }
});
```

Comment: That is a bit heavy handed and you should use .filter(function(){return (condition to match)}) not .each

Answer (score 1):

Use the not() method http://api.jquery.com/not/

```
$("a").not(document.getElementById('gallery'))
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a hasClass selector in jquery you can use that. 
try this.

check for class only

```
$('a').each(function(){
if (!$(this).hasClass('gallery'))
  {
       //code here
  }
});
```

or check for both class and id

```
$('a').each(function(){
if (!$(this).hasClass('gallery') && $(this).attr('id').indexOf('gallery') == -1)
  {
       //code here
  }
});
```